# Reduction of Leaf constrained MST p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m to Hamiltonian path p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, np-complete

It is well known that computing a spanning tree that has the minimum possible number of leaves is NP complete. But I cannot figure out a polynomial time reduction of this problem to the hamiltonian path problem.

My exponential reduction:

```
if(hamiltonian path exists for whole graph) 
    min leaves = 1;
    return;
else
    for each vertex of the graph
        if(hamiltonian path exists for this graph after removing the vertex and its incident edges)
            min leaves = 2;
            return;
    continue similarly for the graph deleting 2 vertices, 3 vertices, 4vertices,... until you get a minimum spanning tree with some minimum number of leaves.
```

So, in the worst case, this algorithm will make a total of

```
(N choose 1) + (N choose 2) + (N choose 3) + ....(N choose N) = 2^N
```

calls to the hamiltonian path problem . Hence reduction is exponential.

Please suggest a polynomial time reduction for this problem.

Comment: `computing a spanning tree that has the minimum possible number of trees` --> Hah?

Comment: Reducing this problem to Hamiltonian path doesn't prove that it's NP-complete - are you sure that this is the reduction you want to be doing?

Comment: A polynomial time reduction will prove that the problem is NP complete. But I am sure that this is not the reduction I want to be doing as it does the reduction in exponential time. And I am looking for a polynomial time reduction of this problem to the hamiltonian path problem.

Comment: @NikunjBanka- I'm confused - you are aware that to prove NP-completeness of the constrained MST problem, you would need to reduce Hamiltonian path to constrained MST, and not the other way around?  I guess I'm not sure why you're attempting to do this reduction at all, since it won't prove anything about constrained MST.

Comment: I was asked this question(whether constrained MST problem is NP complete using reduction from hamiltonian path problem) in a homework assignment. Google tells that yes it is. But I cannot find a polynomial time reduction.

Comment: @NikunjBanka- You are doing the reduction backward.  Start with Hamiltonian path and reduce it to leaf-constrained MST.

Comment: @templatetypedef Can you please give some more hints on how to pull this off.

Comment: Hint: What's the minimum number of leaves a spanning tree can have, at all? What would such a tree look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of reducing the algorithm is that if you can show that the Hamiltonian Path problem can be solved using the constrained MST problem, (with a polynomial time reduction), then any polynomial time solution to the MST problem would allow you to solve the Hamiltonian Path problem in polynomial time. As this is impossible, it would prove the constrained MST problem cannot be solved in polynomial time.

What you are trying to do is the opposite - proving that the Hamiltonian Path problem is at least as hard as the constrained MST problem.

Note that you stated in the comments that your assignment was to reduce **from** the Hamiltonian Path problem, and in the question you said you were trying to reduce **to** the Hamiltonian Path problem.

You can easily solve the Hamiltonian Path problem using the constrained MST problem, as a Hamiltonian Path will always be a spanning tree with 2 (or 0 for a Hamiltonian Cycle) leaves.